# Unable to access or create database using the 'Influx' command in influxdb docker image

Tags: linux, docker, influxdb, influxdb-2

I've created a container and executed it for influxdb. Now as the previous versions we could access the databases by going inside the influx shell with influx command. But when I type the influx command I get list of help command. Any one here has an idea how to create database in influxdb 2.x inside docker container.[image]

Answer (score 6):

influxdb 2.0 is very different from 1.x. `databases` don't exist anymore, they are named `buckets` now... There is a [whole page](https://devconnected.com/how-to-create-a-database-on-influxdb-1-7-2-0/) explaining the different ways in which you can create a bucket in influxdb 2.0. Look specially at sections IV and V.

In short there are two alternatives:

- using the cli: `influx bucket create -n <bucketname> --org-id <org-id> -r 10h -t <secret-token>`. Read further on the page on how to get your org id and token.
- use the UI (located at http://localhost:9999 by default)